# How to set repeated fields in protobuf before building the message?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Let's say I have a Message with a repeated field:

```
Message Foo {
    repeated Bar bar = 1;
}
```

Now I want to insert `n` Bar objects into the field bar, each is created in a loop.

```
for (i=0; i < n; i++){
    //Add Bar into foo
}
//Build foo after loop
```

Is this possible or do I need all `n` bar fields at the same time before building the foo Object?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When you use the protoc command to generate the java object it will create a Foo Object which will have its own builder method on it.

You will end up doing something like this

```
//Creates the builder object 
Builder builder = Package.Foo.newBuilder();
//populate the repeated field.
builder.addAll(new ArrayList<Bar>());
//This should build out a Foo object
builder.build();
```

To add individual objects you can do something like this.

```
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    builder.addBar(bar);
    builder.build();
```

Edited with the use case you've requested.

Comment: Yes this is what i do now, but i was hoping to find something where i can insert the inner objects one by one.

Comment: edited the message, there should be an option to pass in the individual objects one by one as well.

Comment: How does one do this with a one-liner?

Answer (score 5):

```
List<Bar> barList= new Arraylist();
barList.add(new Bar());
```

Then set the list of Bar in the Foo

```
Foo foo =  Foo.newBuilder()
        .addAllBar(barList)
        .build;
```

You can set only one value for Bar

```
Foo foo =  Foo.newBuilder()
        .addBar(new Bar())
        .build;
```